# CSV в Python. Каким образом сделать проверку по столбцам?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Всем привет. 
Очень нубовский вопрос, на котором я застрял.
Имеем CSV файл, который будет хранить в себе определённый текст, но при этом только в одном столбце. Задача состоит в том, чтобы проверить если текст не состоит в других столбцах при этом использовать дефолтный модуль csv в python.

Вот что у меня получилось родить (и понятно что оно не работатет):

```
import csv

with open("some_csv.csv", 'r') as f:
     read = csv.read(f)
     for column in read:
         if column != [0]:
            break
```

Заранее признателен за советы!

Comment: Переведите пожалуйста, что написано вот в этой фразе: "проверить если текст не состоит в других колонках при этом использовать дефолтный csv в python." Во-первых, "состоит ИЗ", а "в других колонках" - НАХОДИТСЯ.  Поэтому непонятно, что вы хотите проверить. Во-вторых, что такое "дефолтный csv". В третьих - "файл будет хранить в себе определённый текст, но при этом только в одной колонке". Так про какие "другие колонки" идет речь? В четвертых -  "ЕСЛИ текст не состоит в других колонках" ТО что?

Comment: дефолтный это значит модуль, который уже включен в python. 
Прочитать csv и проверить если пользователь не ввел во 2,3,4... колонки текст, то есть, колонки я подразумеваю разделитель запятой. Если же текст есть и в первой и во второй и в третей колонке - завершить скрипт. Если текст только в первой колонке (как и необходимо) - вывести что всё ок. Как-то сложно это всё расписывать.. Сори если не понятно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Упустил в условии len()

```
import csv

with open("some_csv.csv", 'r') as f:
    read = csv.reader(f)
    for col in read:
        if len(col) != 1:
            break
        else:
            print(col)
```